# changing a column based on it's highest value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column, num, and I'm trying to update the column such that `num = num / MAX(num)`. Now the thing is that MAX(num) should remain static throughout the update.. it should be the MAX prior to the update. I was wondering whether this was possible to do in one SQL statement. The obvious solution otherwise that I'm currently using it

`val = select max(num) from table;`

`update table set num = num / val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain of the syntax, or what the performance implications would be, but how about something like this?

```
UPDATE table
JOIN (SELECT MAX(num) AS val FROM table)
SET num = num / val;
```

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias in mysql. Otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that

```
SET @val = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM table);
UPDATE table SET num = num / @val;
```

most interfaces will allow you to execute the above as one statement.

At the same time, the expected

```
UPDATE table
SET num = num / (SELECT MAX(num) FROM table);
```

does not work as you can't have a subquery on the same table you are trying to update in mysql.

However

```
UPDATE table
SET num = num / (SELECT val FROM (SELECT MAX(num) AS val FROM table) tmp);
```

creates a temp table out of subquery and bypass the limitation.